# Проблема с переменной во VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть небольшое тестовое приложение на VueJs. Суть проблемы в том, что, когда при вызове функции close должно происходить присвоение this.selected_tab = 'collections', по факту это не происходит. Не понятно почему.

```js
Vue.component('collections', {
    template: "#collections",
    data: function () {
        return {
            collections: ['collection1', 'collection2', 'collection3']
        }
    }
})

var main = new Vue({
        el: "#main",
        data: {
            selected_tab: 'collections',
            tabs: ['collections'],
            lists: [
                'collection1',
                'collection2',
                'collection3'
            ]
        },
        methods: {
            showTab: function (tab) {
                this.selected_tab = tab;
            },
            selectList: function (selected) {
                console.log(selected)
                this.tabs.push(selected)
                this.selected_tab = selected;
            },
           isActive: function (tab) {
                var result = false;
                if (this.selected_tab === tab) {
                    result = true;
                }
                return result;
            },
            close: function (index) {
                this.selected_tab = 'collections';
                this.tabs.splice(index, 1);
                console.log(this)
            }
        }
});
```

```css
body {
    padding: 10px;
    font: 14px "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

a {
    color: #00B7FF;
}

ul.nav {
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}

.nav li {
    float: left;
}

ul.nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    background-color: #d4d8f4;
    border: 1px #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
}

ul.nav a:hover {
    background-color: #77de9a;
    color: #8f34be;
}

ul.nav a:active {
    background-color: #77de9a;
    color: #8f34be;
}

ul.nav a.active {
    background: #77de9a;
}

th.active {
    color: #fff;
}

th.active .arrow {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<template id="collections">
  <div class="collections">
    <div v-for="collection in collections"><a @click.prevent="$emit('select', collection)" href="">{{ collection }}</a></div>
  </div>
</template>

<div id="main" @keyup.v="test">
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li v-for="key, index in tabs"><a href="" @click.prevent="showTab(key)" :class="{ active: isActive(key) }" :id="key">{{ key }}
          <button @click.prevent="close(index)" v-if="key !== 'collections'">x</button></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <collections v-if="selected_tab === 'collections'" v-on:select="selectList"></collections>
</div>
```

Вот ссылка на это приложение: https://jsfiddle.net/pzbv3bny/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что событие клика [всплывает](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-bubbling) и вызывается оба обработчика:

1. обработчик для `<button>` — `close(index)`
2. обработчик для `<li>` — `showTab(key)`

Чтобы этого избежать можно использовать модификатор [`.stop`](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9):

```
<button @click.prevent.stop="close(index)">x</button>
```